# Twin subscribes block forkJoin subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

Here is the test, in the ngInit of any angular component:

```
console.log('a');

observableFoo$.subscribe(x => console.log('b'));
observableNotFoo$.subscribe(() => console.log('c'));

forkJoin([
  observableFoo$,
  observableNotFoo$
]).subscribe(([foo, ntFoo]) => {
  console.log('d');
});
```

The ObservableFoo$ will fire 2 times, that is behaviour that I need, this observable will observe a value that can quickly change during the initialisation.

result is :

```
a
b
b
c
```

And d never log.
So, I first tried to do the same, but with only ObservableNotFoo$ just to be sure I can forkJoin on a single Observable (useless but it works), then I tried the same thing with ObservableFoo$ and it's not working.

It seems forkJoin just doesn't accept subscriptions that will fire twice. Is that so? Seem's really strange...

** EDIT : **

```
observableFoo$ = initFoo(this.id); 

observableNotFoo$ = of('notFoo');
```

```
initFoo(id: string): Observable<any> {
 const content = this.store.select({
      filterBy: entity => entity.id === id
    }).pipe(
      flatMap(v => {
        const value = v[0];
        if (!value) {
          return httpRequest.get(this.baseUrl + '/' + id).pipe(map(val => {
            this.store.add(val);
            return val;
          }));
        }
        return of(value);
      })
    );
    return content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what both observables really are?

Comment: Done, I removed some levels of abstraction to make it more clear.

Simply, I have a store, if it's not initialise, it will be soon, so the event fire twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Scenario, the Observables are not completed. `ForkJoin` is usually used for the observables that are completed i.e HTTP requests.

So For this scenario, you can use `CombineLatest`.

```
combineLatest(observableFoo$, observableNotFoo$).subscribe(([foo, ntFoo]) => {
    console.log(foo, ntFoo);
})
```

for more information visit : [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

Answer (score 1):

`forkJoin` waits all observables to be completed, until then it will not emit anything, as it is said in documentation here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Please consider using:

- `combineLatest` if you want it to be fired every time when any of
  observables emits something. [Link](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest)
- `withLatestFrom` if you want it to fire
  when one of the observables emits something (first one). [Link](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom)
- `zip` if you want to combine every pair [Link](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/zip)

In order to get it done with `forkJoin`, you have to complete both of your observables, it can be done in many ways, for instance use `take(n)`, `takeUntil($end)` or `takeWhile(x => x > 5)` etc. After last observable completed, you will see 'd' in console.